# Affection test for session manage

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

I have problem with understanding `@Transactional` annotation in spring and in common how it works.

I have this snippet(VacancyService class marked as transactional):

```
    @TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml" })
    public class AbstractServiceTest  extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{
           ....
           @Test
        public void delete(){
//here session opens and transaction starts 
            vacancyService.delete(vacancy.getId());

            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();

            Vacancy vacancyFromDb = vacancyService.findById(vacancy.getId());   

            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();

            Assert.assertNull(vacancyFromDb);
//here transactions commit and session close
        }
}
```

and second snippet:

```
@Controller
public class VacancyMenuController extends AbstractController{

...
   @RequestMapping("/path")
   public String delete(Model model){
  //here session opens and transaction starts 
                 vacancyService.delete(vacancy.getId());
 //here transactions commit and session close

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();

 //here session opens and transaction starts    
    Vacancy vacancyFromDb = vacancyService.findById(vacancy.getId());
//here transactions commit and session close    

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();


    }
}
```

Please, read comments in code and fix my mistakes.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question, it seems like you just want code. That's off-topic on SO.

Comment: I want to know:Comments about session and transaction in code rights or wrong?

Comment: Why don't you run it and see. We don't know what results you're expecting.

Comment: How can I check, that uses concrete transaction and session ?